# Understanding swap function in java with a program

Tags: java

As I have read online that Java is pass by value and a general swap function won't swap the two values. I also read that it's not possible to swap the values of primitive types. I am wondering why the following program works and displays different valies after swap ?

```
public class swapMe {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 10 , y = 20;

        System.out.println("Before");
        System.out.println("First number = " + x);
        System.out.println("Second number = " + y);

        int temp = x;
        x = y;
        y = temp;

        System.out.println("After");
        System.out.println("First number = " + x);
        System.out.println("Second number = " + y);
    }
}
```

Is it like somewhere, the original values of `x = 10` and `y = 20` are still stored somewhere and the swapped values displayed are not correct? Please advise. Thanks

Comment: (facepalm!)  are you passing those values to any method, in order to check the ***swap function won't swap*** theory???

Comment: Value of `x` stored in `temp` after `int temp = x;` executes. And so on. They aren't "somewhere", you yourself told compiler exactly where they should be.

Comment: You need to understand the difference between literal **swapping** and exchanging + assigning values between variables. Additionally - "*As I have read online that Java is pass by value*" you never passed any variables to any methods in your example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not *entirely* sure where you're getting that information, but let's take this one at a time.

> As I have read online that Java is pass by value and a general swap function won't swap the two values.

**Correct**...if the expectation of the swap is to happen by virtue of calling a method.

```
 public void swap(int x, int y) {
     int tmp = x;
     x = y;
     y = tmp;
 }

 // meanwhile, in main
 int x = 10;
 int y = 20;
 swap(x, y);
 System.out.println(x); // still prints 10
 System.out.println(y); // still prints 20
```

**Incorrect**...if the swap happens *inside* the method and is utilized somehow.

```
 public void swap(int x, int y) {
     int tmp = x;
     x = y;
     y = tmp;
     System.out.println(x);  // will print 20 from main
     System.out.println(y);  // will print 10 from main
 }

 // meanwhile, in main
 int x = 10;
 int y = 20;
 swap(x, y);
 System.out.println(x); // still prints 10
 System.out.println(y); // still prints 20
```

> I also read that it's not possible to swap the values of primitive types.

No, this is perfectly possible to do.  You can always reassign variables.

As to why your example above works, it's because you're holding onto one of the values while you reassign one of its variables.  You're basically putting one value to the side while you copy it over.

Slowly...

```
int x = 10;
int y = 20;
int tmp = x; // tmp = 10
x = y;  // x = 20, tmp = 10
y = tmp;  x = 20, y = 10; tmp = 10 (but that doesn't matter)
```

Comment: You technically can't "swap" values between primitives: `4` will stay `4` whatever you do with it. OP just confuses swapping and assignments.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov:  It isn't like Python's style of swapping in which you don't need an intermediate variable, but reassignment is congruent to swapping when used in this context.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Python also uses third variable, it just won't show that to you.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov:  I did say *you* don't need it.  Python *likely* needs it, but you don't need to invoke it.  `x, y = y, x` is the most common form of that for defined values of `x` and `y`.